# How to get data from django orm inside an asynchronous function?

Tags: python, django

I need to retrieve data from the database inside an asynchronous function. If I retrieve only one object by executing e.g:

```
users = await sync_to_async(Creators.objects.first)()
```

everything works as it should. But if the response contains multiple objects, I get an error.

```
@sync_to_async
def get_creators():
    return Creators.objects.all()

async def CreateBotAll():
    users = await get_creators()

    for user in users:
        print(user)
```

Tracing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/django/django_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/django/django_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 
181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/django/django_venv/src/reseller/views.py", line 29, in test
asyncio.run(TgAssistant.CreateBotAll())
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
return loop.run_until_complete(main)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "/home/django/django_venv/src/reseller/TgAssistant.py", line 84, in CreateBotAll
for user in users:
File "/home/django/django_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 
280, in __iter__
self._fetch_all()
File "/home/django/django_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 
1324, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
File "/home/django/django_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 
51, in __iter__
results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
File "/home/django/django_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", 
line 1173, in execute_sql
cursor = self.connection.cursor()
File "/home/django/django_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 31, 
in inner
raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - 
use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

I made it work that way:

```
@sync_to_async
def get_creators():
    sql = Creators.objects.all()
    x = [creator for creator in sql]
    return x
```

Isn't there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 4.1  you can do the following:

```
async for creator in Creators.objects.all():
    print(creator)
```

And you can replace this with filter and the like as long as the expression doesn't cause the query to be evaluated.

There are also async versions of get, delete etc prefixed with an 'a' so your

```
users = await sync_to_async(Creators.objects.first)()
```

can be replaced with:

```
user = await Creators.object.afirst()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try wrap get_creators response into list:

```
@sync_to_async
def get_creators():
    return list(Creators.objects.all())
```